# Google Analytics Property Settings Default URL for subdomain tracking with analytics.js

Tags: google-analytics

My main web site is using `www.site.com` URL and I have a bunch of subdomains (`blog.site.com`, `docs.site.com`) that I want to track as the same Google Analytics property.

I use `analytics.js` which according to Google docs doesn't require any additional configuration to track subdomains:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'site.com');
```

My **default URL** in Google Analytics Property Settings is set to `www.site.com` as shown below, however I don't get any data from subdomains.

Do I have to change the **default URL** to `site.com` (it gets redirected to `www.site.com`)?

[image]

Comment: Must integrate `google analytic` script into any web pages to follow, even if the docs blog pages.

Comment: In case you are using different content management system for your root domain (site.com) and sub-domain (blog.site.com), you will need to install the GA script on both sites / systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Default URL` setting is used only in reporting and does not impact the data being collected. To see your subdomains, you need to add a `Hostname` secondary dimension.